# how to copy a part of a text file and paste it in the end of the same line after adding semicolon , but for 1000 lines

Tags: replace, copy-paste

I have a text file which had 1000 lines, and I want to copy a part of every line and past it at the end of the same line after adding a semicolon, but that must be done for 1000 lines.

I have imported the text file to excel so I can do it, but I did not get any hint to do it at one go.

here is for example how look likes the first line:

```
{"loginId":"gcdmtest_bp_pr_acc_po_20000@trash-mail.com","password":"test1234"};dc9b88ce-f26e-43fa-a2c1-6b67cc628404
```

I want to add a semicolon at the end of the line, and then copy the email pattern at the end of the same line like:

```
;gcdmtest_bp_pr_acc_po_20000@trash-mail.com
```

Comment: What tools do yo have at hand? A decent text editor? A shell? Another programming language? Mechanical Turk?

Comment: I use the simple notepad of Win7, and I've said before I opent it with excel,and it does offer the possibilty to seperate the columns, but after copying the email in the end of the line, and try to copy the whole in a notepad, I notice it contains space in every line where I copy the email like so: {"loginId":" gcdmtest_bp_pr_acc_po_20000@trash-mail.com ","password":"test1234"};dc9b88ce-f26e-43fa-a2c1-6b67cc628404     gcdmtest_bp_pr_acc_po_20000@trash-mail.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm just giving you a general guide to do this.

- Read the text file (using C#, Java, whatever you are comfortable with)
- Use a for loop to go through each line, extract the email portion, then add to the end of the line.
- Save the new text file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys I found the solution on this code:

```
File mFile = new File(newfile);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mFile);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(mFile))) ;
            String result = "";
            String line = "";

            while( (line = br.readLine()) != null){
            String emailpattern = line.substring(12, 54);

             result += line + ";"+emailpattern + System.getProperty("line.separator"); 


            }

            result = result;

            mFile.delete();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mFile);

        fos.write(result.getBytes());


            fos.flush();
```